# Does the MacBook show FaceTime missed calls?

Tags: macbook-pro, facetime

I use my MacBook Air for FaceTime calls, while a friend calls me using an iPad 2.

Since I don't always keep my Air turned on all the time, my friend's calls often end up unanswered. However, it's very rare that I see these on my Mac. It was only once that I actually saw a missed call in my FaceTime.

Does FaceTime actually store missed call information on Apple's servers? Should they appear in my MacBook once I turn it on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will show up in your missed calls list in FaceTime.app (even if your computer is turned off at the time):

[image]

So yeah, FaceTime stores missed call information on Apple’s servers. It will show up in FaceTime.app, but you need to open FaceTime.app for it to show.

Comment: OK...so those were probably connectivity issues at my friend's end when I didn't see the missed calls? I'm trying to figure out why I don't see many of them.

Comment: If the call couldn’t connect to Apple’s servers for some reason (could be a connectivity issue, or maybe your friend is behind a firewall?), then there’d be no way to see the “missed” call.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running iOS 9 and I too don't get missed call notifications. Also, there is no tab as missed now. The 2 tabs are video, Audio for video and audio calls respectively on both iOS and OS X. When any device is not connected to the Internet and someone did FaceTime you, there won't be a 'notification' anywhere. I've submitted several bug reports but it hasn't been taken care of.